# Bash script check actually date files on ftp

Tags: bash, ftp, lftp

i have simple script :

```
lftp user@server -e "cd dir && ls -ltr ;exit" > list.txt

if files=$(cat list.txt | grep "`date | awk '{print $2" "$3}'`") ; then
     echo "$files" | mailx -s "File exists"  name@name.com
else
    echo "$files" | mailx -s "File not exists" name@name.com
end if
```

problem is because this grep date from file not working corectly, sometimes is working.

Can someone tell me what is better way to check on ftp server if actual date file exists and send me email?

Comment: lftp server -e "cd /directoryh && ls -ltr ;exit" > list.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are three possible problems here. The first is that `date | awk '{print $2" "$3}'` includes a comma on the end of the day number. The second is that the day number is space padded by `ls` and `date`, but `awk` will be stripping the padding. The third is that the terminator for `if` in `bash` is `fi` rather then `end if`.

Try

```
if files=$(grep "`date '+%b %e'`" list.txt); then
     echo "$files" | mailx -s "File exists"  name@name.com
else
    echo "$files" | mailx -s "File not exists" name@name.com
fi
```

The `%e` in `date` assumes `ls` returns a space-padded day number. If your system uses a zero-padded day number, try `%d`.

Comment: not working, same result , cd ok, write to file ok, and if grep here is problem

Comment: Doh. Try the edited version. I've tried it on my system, and it works as expected, for what that is worth. If it doesn't work, could you include some output from the `list.txt` file in the question? Maybe `ls -lrt` is using a weird date format?

Comment: -rw-r-----    1 user group         1155359 Jun 04 10:17 file_F_000000021051_0000000910_01.txt

Comment: file with ls -ltr looks like this

Comment: i have changed date '+%b %e to date '+%b %d and it working!

Comment: Great, well done! I've edited my answer to mentioned space and zero padding options. If I could have an uprate or a recommend answer, that'd be great as I need the points :-)